# Microsoft Graph SDK: How many steps will be executed in a batch request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, batch-request

currently I am working with the MS Graph SDK to retrieve and move messages from one folder to another after some business logic. To move the messages/e-mails I use the batch request functionality. By trying to move 6 messages in a batch request only 4 of them will be handled and moved. The 2 messages stayed in the source folder. After I trigger the process another time the remaining 2 messages have been moved to the target folder.

Here is the code where the request steps will be added to the batch request (imagine that in the list of *idsOfMessagesToMove* are 6 elements):

```
for (String idOfMessageToMove : idsOfMessagesToMove) {

        MessageMoveRequest messageMoveRequest = this.graphServiceClient.users(EMAIL_ACCOUNT)
                .mailFolders(MailboxFolderEnum.MAILBOX_FOLDER_INBOX.getFolderName()).messages(idOfMessageToMove)
                .move(MessageMoveParameterSet.newBuilder().withDestinationId(mailFolderDestination.getFolderName())
                        .withDestinationId(mailFolderDestination.getFolderName()).build()).buildRequest();

        messageMoveRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        batchRequestContent.addBatchRequestStep(messageMoveRequest, HttpMethod.POST, messageMoveRequest.body);
}
```

Can somebody confirm that always only 4 steps in a batch request will be executed, and if not do you have a clue why this happen?

Many thanks in advance.

Best,
Ka-Ming

Answer (score 0):

Here... this link mentions the limit of 4 concurrent requests attempting to perform an operation on the same mailbox and the concurrency error you'll get if you go over that :

[Mailbox concurrency limit issue](https://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2020/09/the-mailboxconcurrency-limit-and-using.html)